# Can't import SlidingUpPanel library into eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, wordpress, slidingpanelayout

I'm trying to import the SlidingUpPanel library by umano into Eclipse so I can work on the WordPress Android app.

BUT eclipse will not let me import the library, it will only let me import the demo entitled "DemoActivity."

[image]
As You can see only the demo can be checked, the library (which is what I want) cannot be checked and is displayed in gray.

How do I import the SlidingPanelLibrary so I can finally have a clean WordPress application to work on...??

Sorry if this is a noob question, I do not have a lot of experience with importing external libraries.

**UPDATE**: Just use Android Studio and the Gradle build system.

Comment: you cant add if you have other library with the same name did you check that?

Comment: You already have `library` named project in your workspace?

Comment: I do have a library named library, it's the 'PasscodeLock' library. What should I do? Rename/Refractor the 'passcodeLock' library?

Comment: Thank you so much! Renaming any library just named "library" did the trick. Thank you so much for saving me and replying so quickly!

Answer (score 0):

For importing library correctly with android, you need to do some manipulation to "convert" gradle project to eclipse:

- Create an empty project, named with the lib name, and mark it "As Library", **AND** don't forget to uncheck "Create Activity" and "Create Icon", they will be useless
- Download the github as a Zip, and extract it in another folder
- In your project folder, remove everything in the /res/ folder
- Copy content of /lib-master/library/java/main/res/ into your /project/res/ folder
- Do the same for /lib-master/library/java/main/java/ into your /project/src/
- Don't forget to copy /lib-master/library/java/main/AndroidManifest.xml to /project/
- Refresh with eclipse and your done!